# Is slavery legal in Magnimar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, golarion

Can a person legally keep slaves in Magnimar and Varisia as a whole?

Any official references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

[From the Pathfinder wiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Slavery) :

> Varisia: The city of Kaer Maga has conflicting attitudes to slavery. Slaves can be bought in Downmarket, and are particularly common in the Ankar-Te district, but in the The Bottoms district enslaving another is a capital offence.

However, [according to James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rkd8?Is-slavery-legal-in-Magnimar), slavery is illegal in Magnimar holdings.